# Recommendation system using spark ml

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning

I'm following the [documentation example](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0-preview/ml-collaborative-filtering.html) to build a recommendation system 
, Im creating ALS constructor all fine

```
 val als = new ALS()
  .setMaxIter(maxIterations)
  .setRegParam(regressionParam)
  .setUserCol("user_id")
  .setItemCol("item_id")
  .setRatingCol("rating")

val model = als.fit(trainData)
val predictions = model.transform(testData)
println("predictions"+predictions.show(80))

val evaluator = new RegressionEvaluator()
  .setMetricName("rmse")
  .setLabelCol("rating")
  .setPredictionCol("prediction")
val rmse = evaluator.evaluate(predictions)
println(s"Root-mean-square error = $rmse")
predictions
```

I train the model, set everything up but my main problem here is that I can predict with test data which returns the prediction factor for each item id I pass to it but I actually need that the model can suggest me items from an user_id not predicting how suitable an item id can be by adding a prediction column. does            org.apache.spark.ml.recommendation.ALS can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently to recommend 10 top items for user with user_id = 1, you must do something like:

```
val predictionsForUser1 = predictions
    .where(col("user_id") === 1)
    .orderBy(col("predictions").desc)
    .limit(10)
```

In of next Spark versions it will be implemented in more user-friendly way

Comment: ok good to know! another thing I'm kinda new to ML, why is it bad to train and test with the same data?

Comment: Model can overfit to test data, which means it will perfectly predict values in test dataset, but when you change dataset the predictions will be very bad. Using two separate datasets allows us to avoid overfitting

Comment: ok thanks! last thing if i do it like in the example, I have training test data like this       user_id | item_id | rating  the problem I got is that the model is predicting based on item_ids so its not recommending me different item_ids its just telling me how suitable (ordering by prediction and limiting results) are the same item_ids associated to training data, I need the model to recommend me different items should i make some sort of distinc so i can test diferrent item_ids or theres another way?

Comment: Well, query that I've posted created 10 recommendations for specific user. It should be distinct, of course if your dataset has also exactly one connection between each user and item. If you have problems with doubled data, then please look at your dataset, it seems to be incorrect and have doubled data

Comment: @RaulH I hope this answer is helpful -  then please mark is as accepted; if not, please write more what you need